# Why do I add time in my FPS (Frames per second) tracker? (Java)

Tags: java, frame-rate

I had help making my FPS tracker, but I don't understand why I have to add `previousTime += 1000;` after printing the fps. If anyone knows tell me. Also if you know why he added the render twice, please explain. Here is my code:

```
public void run()
{
    int frames = 0;
    double unprocessedSeconds = 0;
    long previousTime = System.nanoTime();
    double secondsPerTick = 1 / 60.0;
    int tickCount = 0;
    boolean ticked = false;
    while(running)
    {
        //check ticker code
        long currentTime = System.nanoTime();
        long passedTime = currentTime - previousTime;
        previousTime = currentTime;
        unprocessedSeconds = passedTime / 1000000000.0;
        while(unprocessedSeconds > secondsPerTick)
        {
            tick();
            unprocessedSeconds -= secondsPerTick;
            ticked = true;
            tickCount++;
            if(tickCount % 60 == 0)
            {
                //System.out.println(frames + " fps");
                previousTime += 1000;
                fps = frames;
                frames = 0;
            }
        }
        if(ticked)
        {
            render();
            frames++;
        }
        render();
        frames++;
    }
```

Comment: Ask the person that helped you because you probably don't have to. 1000 is mathematically irrelevant when you have nano time (there are 1.000.000.000 ns per second)

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot easier for the `render` method to just track the number of times it was called, which is the number of frames rendered, and once per second outputting its current count. Since it's the `render` method it would seem likely that it is also responsible for "rendering" the counter on-screen somewhere, unless this is being logged to a file or a text console.

At the same time the count is output, also reset it to zero, and start the count again. FPS counters just aren't that complicated, and don't require division or tick counting, or whatever. It's just a freakin' count that (typically) is updated on-screen once per second.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like he is counting seconds in the previousTime variable.  Every tick he adds part of a second to the unprocessedSeconds.  Once the unprocessedSeconnds gets to 60 he adds 1000 because it ticks a full second on the previousTime.

Another way, every 60 times through the tick section a second is added.  Apparently he expects the render to happen 60 times a second.

I've seen the extra render() before because they try to do a "poor man's" version of syncing to the time.